# What is the difference between type and virtualType

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, virtualtype

In the `di.xml` that comes with Magento2 there is a node `type` and a node `virtualType`. My questions is what is this `virtualType` and in what case should it be used instead of `type`?

In some places it looks like a symbolic link or rewrite:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
```

Where one full path gets changed into another but in other places it appears to be used as a way to define a shorter alias.

```
<virtualType name="lessFileSourceBase" type="Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Base">
```

Comment: I have no idea (yet) what they even mean but you can start digging from here: `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom::convert`. There is a `switch` statement in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Marius, I am also wondering if `lessFileSourceBase` is limited to the xml or if that can also be used outside. Guess I better get digging.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Virtual types are a way to inject different dependencies into existing classes without affecting other classes.

For example, the `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage` class takes a `$namespace` argument in its constructor, which defaults to the value 'default', and you could use the `type` definition to change the namespace to 'core'.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">core</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

The above config would make it so that **all** instances of `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage` have a namespace of 'core'.  Using a virtual type allows for the equivalent of a sub-class to be created, where only the sub-class has the altered argument values.

In the codebase we see the following two configurations:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">core</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Magento\Framework\Session\Generic">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

The first snippet creates a virtual type for `Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage` which alters the namespace, and the second inject the virtual type into `Magento\Framework\Session\Generic`.  This allows `Magento\Framework\Session\Generic` to be customized without affecting other classes that also declare a dependency on `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris finally some logical justification i found

Comment: That was simple and the best demonstration.

Comment: This answer is better then Magento official doc

Comment: `<type>` is using a virtual class which doesn't actually exist. This way the argument modification in `virtualType` will take effect only when the class using the virtualType is initialized which is `Magento\Framework\Session\Generic` in the example

Comment: I found an example that can help us to undestand more deeply https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-design-patterns-preferences-virtual-types/

Comment: @chris - You make this a 'piece of cake' to understand, thankyou so much!

Comment: @chris - Can we use a custom class in place of 'Magento\Framework\Session\Generic' as well, correct ?

Answer (score 35):

Another way to understand virtual types -

Let's say that you have a class `\Class1`, which has the following constructor -

```
public function __construct(\Class2 $argOfClass1){...}
```

And `\Class2` has the following constructor -

```
public function __construct(\Class3 $argOfClass2){...}
```

Now, you want to change the type of `$argOfClass2` from `\Class3` to `\Class4`, but only when `\Class2` is used as `$argOfClass1`.

The "old" way to do that would be to add the following in `di.xml` -

```
<type name="Class1">
    <arguments>
         <argument name="argOfClass1" xsi:type="object">Class5</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

where `\Class5` is the following:

```
class \Class5 extends \Class2{
    public function __construct(\Class4 $argOfClass2){...}
}
```

Instead of using this way, you can use the **virtual types** to accomplish the same, by adding the following to `di.xml`:

```
<virtualType name="Class5" type="Class2">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="argOfClass2" xsi:type="string">Class4</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Class1">
    <arguments>
         <argument name="argOfClass1" xsi:type="object">Class5</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

As you can see, using the **virtual type** saved you the work of creation of `Class5`.

For further reference I suggest to read Alan Storm's article regarding virtual types in Magento2 - http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_virtual_types/

[Practical way using magento2 module](https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-virtualtype-practical-example/)

Comment: good expalination ,

Comment: Easy to understand. Thanks for sharing such a basic example.

Comment: "As you can see, using the virtual type saved you the work of creation of Class5" - Grasping this concept helped me understand the purpose of Virtual Types. Thanks for making this more clear for me!

Answer (score 11):

In the same `di.xml` file I found that `lessFileSourceBase` is passed as an argument for `lessFileSourceBaseFiltered` that is passed as an argument for `lessFileSourceBaseSorted` that is passed as an argument for type `Magento\Framework\Less\File\Collector\Aggregated`.

I found no other occurrence of `lessFileSourceBase` (or `lessFileSource` ) in an other file except `di.xml` from the core module. Only in some cache files but those are not important.

I guess if you are not going to use the virtual type in a PHP class, but only in the `di` xml files then you are not required to make it look like a class name and you can use an alias.

But this is just pure speculation.
It will be "fun" to try to create a class and inject in its constructor an instance of `lessFileSourceBase` to see how it behaves.

Comment: you missed the quotes around the word fun ;)

Comment: @DavidManners. Right. I fixed it. :)

Comment: @Marius: If you alter `\Magento\Framework\Session\Generic` source file to depend on `Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage` instead of `StorageInterface` you should get a 'Class Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage does not exist' exception.

The reason being that ObjectManager doesn't create an instance of the virtualType, but just uses that to determine what arguments to provide for the constructor of the concrete type that is referenced by the virtualType definition (`Magento\Framework\Session\Storage` for the above example).

Comment: [Can see this in the Factory](https://github.corp.ebay.com/magento2/magento2/blob/e14d11f74283213a6beb0518f79739e92b19c7ed/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Factory.php#L169-L181), where `$requestedType` represents the virtual type and is used to gather arguments, but `$type` is the concrete type that the virtualType maps to and is used for the object instantiation call.

Comment: So even if `lessFileSourceBase` was in a more namespace\class type style, it wouldn't allow for direct reference by another php class, just for injection via the di.xml

Comment: Just had so much fun with this.