# Magento 2: Virtual Type Naming Convention

Tags: php, magento2, dependency-injection, virtualtype

**Date: June 1, 2015 (given the changing nature of Magento 2)**

In Magento 2, you can [configure a "virtual type"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33103/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-virtualtype) in a module's `di.xml` configuration file.  These virtual types allow you to change the arguments of a specific injected dependency.

In the core Magento 2 code, there appears to be two naming conventions for virtual types.  In the first, a virtual type has a name that appears identical to a real PHP class name.

```
#File: app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/etc/di.xml
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Pool" ...
```

in the second, a simple, backslash-less string is used

```
#File: app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/di.xml
<virtualType name="advancedSearchFilterList" ...
```

Is there any practical difference to the above two naming conventions?  i.e. does the name you chose for a `virtualType` have any impact on its behavior, or is it just a globally unique string that identifies the type so you can use it later on.

Comment: well for developers learning Magento2, this is quite a confusion when they check an argument which has a class name, and instead it turns out to be a virtual type, i guess well pointed out here http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_virtual_types

Comment: See https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Virtual-Types-Naming-Convention/ba-p/61510

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of virtual type is just a globally unique string. There is no difference in behavior for differently named virtual types. We just don't have strong naming convention for virtual types. I personally prefer second approach because it makes it obvious that this is virtual type, not a real class.

Comment: This being a 1.5 yo post, is the conventions still that there is no convention? I should use what ever I want for virtual types, but you still encourage me to use the second approach? Or do you have a new standard by now?

Answer (score 1):

Hi All hope you are doing well.

I have created a easy example video for understanding of virtual type or you can virtual class. I am sharing with you link below, if like this video so please like and subscribe my channel for view more interesting video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3LbBtSwXUQ