# What is the Use of Type and Virtual Types(di.xml) in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di, di.xml

I want to know clear about Type and Virtual Types in di.xml with examples. When we can use it.

Please share simple example to understand concept.

Note please go through the practical examples.

Comment: Did you understand ?
If yes then please explain to us

Answer (score 1):

**Virtual types** are a way to inject different dependencies into existing classes without affecting other classes.

For **Example**, the `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage` class takes a `$namespace` argument in its `constructor`, which defaults to the value **default**, and you could use the `type` definition to change the namespace to **core**.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">core</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

The above config would make it so that **all** instances of `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage` have a namespace of **core**.  Using a virtual type allows for the equivalent of a sub-class to be created, where only the sub-class has the altered argument values.

*In the codebase we see the following two configurations:*

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">core</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Magento\Framework\Session\Generic">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

The first snippet creates a virtual type for `Magento\Core\Model\Session\Storage` which alters the namespace, and the second inject the virtual type into `Magento\Framework\Session\Generic`.  This allows `Magento\Framework\Session\Generic` to be customized without affecting other classes that also declare a dependency on `Magento\Framework\Session\Storage`

Comment: original answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33140/84914