# Dependency Injection (di.xml) - (virtualType vs type) Magento 2 xsi:type='object'

Tags: magento2, di, virtualtype

Can someone please explain when you would use `<type/>` or `<virtualType` in your `di.xml` file?

I want to make sure I understand it correctly..
At the moment, this is what I sort of think the difference is, especially with `xsi:type='object'` as arguments.

#### Type:

```
    <type name='Some\File\Object'>
       <arguments>
          <argument name="someText" xsi:type="string">String Value for This Arg</argument>
          <argument name="someArg" xsi:type="object">Some\Object\Arg\For\This\Arg</argument>
       </arguments>
    </type>
```

#### Virtual Type:

```
<virtualType name='instance1' type='Some\File\Object'>
   <arguments>
      <argument name="someArg" xsi:type="object">Some\Object\Arg\For\This\Arg</argument>
   </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name='instance2' type='Some\File\Object'>
   <arguments>
      <argument name="someArg" xsi:type="object">Some\Other\Object\Arg\For\This\Arg</argument>
   </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

- So the questions I guess:  - This is what I think it does:

  1. `<type/> vs </virtualType>` usage:

     - `<type/>` : This is a singular instance, and everywhere Magento 2 references this type, would it **replace the argument given for every other class that use this object (argument)?**
     - `<virtualType/>` : These ones you are able to call by `name=`, (in my example *instance1, or instance2)* to differentiate their usage at different places.  I then call them and give them different argument values, so they do not interact with each other?
  2. Is this how you would use `type` and `virtualType`.... one/more objects and then 'override' them for use in other places that do not have any dependency on each other.  For example: creating different log files, **Magento has the main `xsi:type=object` referenced somewhere**, then using virtualTypes I call them using the `name`?
  3. Do I do this (based on `instance1` or `instance2` above) example usage:

**Use Type**

```
   <type name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance1</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
   <type name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance2</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
```

**OR**
**VirtualType**:

```
   <virtualType name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance1</argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>
   <virtualType name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance2</argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>
```

I think the confusion is when do I use `<virtualType/>` elements do I use them in **conjunction with  AND / OR** , especially when I want to use **multiple virtualTypes with just arguments different** (log files for sake of this discussion)

Comment: Check this post with an accepted answer. Well explained when to use virtualType: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33103/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-virtualtype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `<preferance>` - is directive for mapping type to interface
- `<type>` - is directive for configure concrete type
- `<virtualType>` - is directive for create *alias*  for type

Example:

```
class A {
 function __construct(
   AInt $a,
   BInt $b 
 )
}
```

You can not create such class, because it contains link to Interfaces
So you can map interfaces to implementation

preference AInt => AClass, BInt => BClass

so it will work like you define class A like

```
class A {
 function __construct(
   AInt $a,
   BInt $b 
 )
}
```

but lest imagine that some subsystems require class A initiated in different way.

You can do it with defining Class D like

```
class D extends A {
 function __construct(
   AInt $a,
   EClass $b  
 )
}
```

or define `virtualType` D.

So, to answer on your question:

1.1 Yes, it will update type of argument for all instances and subtypes

1.2 Yes, `virtualType` update type of argument only for self  (or other virtual types based on this)

2. Yes, type configuration is global, you need use `virtualType` to overwrite for subsystem

```
   <type name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance1</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
   <type name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance2</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
```

is the same as

```
   <type name='Some\Other\ObjectB'>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="ObjectInstance" xsi:type='object'>instance2</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
```

Magento merges all declarations with same name, so you need use `virtualType` here

Comment: Thank you :)

Your last XML comments made it absolutely clear, the word 'merge' is the key here. Thanks for advice!